# how to redirect my subtask form to task show file in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

in my laravel application I have subtask enter form with this url

```
http://localhost:8000/projects/1/task/6/subtask
```

routes for this

```
Route::post('projects/{projectId}/task/{taskId}/subtask','SubtasksController@store')->name('subtasks.form');
```

subtaskController

```
 public function store(Request $request,$projectId,$taskId)
    {
        $subtask = new Subtask;
        $subtask->subtask_name = $request->input('task_name');
        $subtask->task_id = $taskId;
        $subtask->project_id = $projectId;

        $subtask->save();
        return redirect()->route('tasks.')->with('warning','Title already exists');
        }
```

now I need redirect subtask form to tasks showing form. this is My task url

```
http://localhost:8000/projects/1
```

and route

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/tasks', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@postNewTask',
    'as' => 'projects.tasks.create'
]);
```

taskController

```
public function postNewTask(Request $request,$id, Project $project)
{

    $task = new Task;
    $task->task_name   = $request->input('name');
    $task->body = $request->input('body');
    $task->assign = $request->input('status');
    $task->priority = $request->input('status');
    $task->duedate  = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->input("date")));
    $task->project_id = $id;//$project->id;
    $task->save();
    return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Task created successfully');
}
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: No any idea....

Comment: I need some help

Comment: In your store method you are redirecting to a named route `tasks.`. First, it's quite unusual to end the name with a period. Are you sure you're not missing something? Second, does this named route exist?

Comment: it should as this '('tasks.show')'

Comment: You should know. You're the one who created the routes.